# How do I hide a UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I'm writing a program that detects a change in orientation of the device (portrait to landscape, etc.). When the device is in portrait a collectionview should be displayed and a scrollview should be hidden. When the device is in landscape mode the collectionview should be hidden and the scrollview should be displayed.

Through NSLogs I have confirmed that rotating the device is detected. and the hidden property is being set to YES.

I has essentially the same code working with two scrollviews, but due to performance issues I switched to using a collectionview and now it doesn't work. Any advice would be much appreciated. Thank You!

I have this code in the viewDidAppear method:

```
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(detectOrientation) name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification" object:nil];
```

And this code in the detectOrientation method

```
-(void) detectOrientation {

if (([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) ||
    ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)) {

    [myCollectionView setHidden:YES];
    myPanoramicScrollView.hidden = NO;        
    NSLog(@"collectionView.hidden = %hhd", myCollectionView.hidden);

} else if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait) {

    myPanoramicScrollView.hidden = YES;
    [myCollectionView setHidden:NO];
    NSLog(@"collectionView.hidden = %hhd", myCollectionView.hidden);
}
```

}

Comment: Is `myCollectionView` definitely not `nil` at the point where you set hidden?

Comment: definitely not. It is displaying content when I hide it.

Comment: `myCollectionView` being `nil` and having something on screen are not related. Does the variable `myCollectionView` actually point to anything at the time you are trying to update `hidden`? What is the result of `NSLog(@"%@", myCollectionView);` at this point.

Comment: when myCollection.hidden = YES it logs the following ---> <UICollectionView: 0x999d400; frame = (0 0; 320 568); clipsToBounds = YES; hidden = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x8b3f7b0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x8b41620>; contentOffset: {0, -20}> collection view layout: <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x8bccf20>
2014-02-16 18:17:55.357 CTTRocks[5214:70b]

Comment: Are you sure this is the `collectionView` on screen? Do you see more than one collection view if you `NSLog(@"%@", [self.view recursiveDescription]);`?

Comment: I pasted your recursive description NSLog into my code and it doesn't recognise the method call. Perhaps if you have a project with a collectionview handy you could try and hide it programmatically and see if it works for you?

Comment: Use this in the debugger then with `po [self.view recursiveDescription]`

Comment: didn't do anything, I have Xcode 5 if that makes a difference.

Comment: Where did you actually put the breakpoint?

Comment: sorry, I had forgotten to use a breakpoint. Anyway, now it confirms there is only one collectionview, but the text is too long to paste here. I'll post it in multiple comments if that helps.

Comment: <UIView: 0x8ba2e90; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x8b28cd0>>
   | <UICollectionView: 0x915d400; frame = (0 0; 320 568); clipsToBounds = YES; hidden = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x8a8f530>; layer = <CALayer: 0x8adea20>; contentOffset: {0, -20}> collection view layout: <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x8aec0b0>
   |    | <UIImageView: 0x8ad81a0; frame = (313 564.5; 7 3.5); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8ae0aa0>>

Comment: |    | <UIImageView: 0x8a34dc0; frame = (316.5 0; 3.5 568); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8ae0df0>>
   | <UIScrollView: 0x8a1f4e0; frame = (0 0; 320 568); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+TM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x8b26800>; layer = <CALayer: 0x8adca90>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
   |    | <UIImageView: 0x8af7310; frame = (0 0; 320 568); opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8af73a0>>

Comment: |    | <UIImageView: 0x8bb7910; frame = (316.5 561; 3.5 7); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8b94240>>
   |    | <UIImageView: 0x8a4f200; frame = (313 564.5; 7 3.5); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8a4f290>>

Comment: Is this being updated on the main thread?

Comment: Yes it is, I do use a GCD oncetoken to make sure my main Array only gets loaded once, but I'm quite sure that doesn't take the processing away from the main thread.